# Obtaining results as a matrix in a self created r function

Tags: r, function, loops, matrix, time-series

The following code runs, but does **not** return(950 numeric values) what I expected(want). In the following code `result` is a matrix of 72 rows and 3 columns. **As an output, I would like to have a matrix with 72 columns and** `length(spots)` **rows**. I tried initialising `fcasts<- matrix(0, nrow=length(spots), ncol=72)`, but then code does not run.

```
y<- ts(rnorm(1000),start = 1850, frequency=1)

library(forecast)

#Searching for the best models
order.matrix<-matrix(0,nrow = 3, ncol = 6 * 2 * 6)
 aic.vec<- numeric(6 * 2 * 6)
 k<-1

 for(p in 0:5) for(d in 0:1) for(q in 0:5){
    order.matrix[,k]<-c(p,d,q)
    aic.vec[k]<- AIC(Arima(y, order=c(p,d,q)))
    k<-k+1
 }
 ind<- order(aic.vec,decreasing=F)
 aic.vec<- aic.vec[ind]
 order.matrix<- order.matrix[,ind]
order.matrix<- t(order.matrix)
result<- cbind(order.matrix,aic.vec)


SlideFunction<- function(data, window, step){

    total<- length(data)
    spots<- seq(from=1, to=(total-window), by=step)
    fit<- vector(mode="list",length=72)
    #fcasts<- matrix(0,nrow=length(spots),ncol=72)
    fcasts<- numeric(length(spots))
    for(i in 1:length(spots)){
    for(j in 1:72){

    p<- result[j,1]
    d<- result[j,2]
    q<- result[j,3]

   #Note I am using Arima(in forecast package) not arima
        fit[[j]]<- Arima(data[spots[i]:(spots[i]+window)], order=c(p,d,q), method="CSS")

        fcasts[i]<- forecast(fit[[j]], h=step)$mean 
#I expected(would like to have) 72 one-step ahead prediction for each fcasts i.e, store values for each arima model.

        }

    }
        return(fcasts)
}
SlideFunction(y,50,1)
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: I added the missing library statement but the code above still gives the `Error: object 'result' not found` error. I just want to make sure we're on the same page before I devote time to this, since you said it runs. Do you also get the same error?

Comment: Well I have added code for result as well. I hope the question is more clear now.

Comment: Is it possible to make the programme faster, so that results can be obtained in less time for really large data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
SlideFunction<- function(data, window, step) {
  total<- length(data)
  spots<- seq(from=1, to=(total-window), by=step)
  fcasts<- matrix(0,nrow=length(spots),ncol=72)
  for(i in 1:length(spots)) {
    for(j in 1:72){
      p<- result[j,1]
      d<- result[j,2]
      q<- result[j,3]
      fit <- Arima(data[spots[i]:(spots[i]+window)], order=c(p,d,q), method="CSS")
      fcasts[i, j] <- forecast(fit, h=step)$mean 
      }
    }
  return(fcasts)
  }

SlideFunction(y,50,1)
```

But it takes quite a long time to finish and I don't have patience to wait. I tried using smaller data set:

```
y<- ts(rnorm(100),start = 1850, frequency=1)
```

and 5 instead of 72, knowing that the result is correct.