# Loop for - Generating rolling forecasts with model re-fitting for different ARMA models

Tags: r, loops, forecasting

Suppose that I have the following R loop for ARMA model estimation on in-sample values:

```
USDlogreturns=diff(log(prices))

for(i in 0:10){
    for(j in 0:10){
      fit <- arima(USDlogreturns, order=c(i,0,j), include.mean=TRUE, method="ML")
     }
}
```

Now, I'd need to backtest my model on out-of-sample values. So my question is the following.

How do you tell R to create and return the vector of the means of rolling forecasts with ARMA model re-fitting for all 121 models? These are the conditions to be applied to obtain the required forecasts:

•   USDlogreturns: vector of 1962 daily observations covering the period 2010-08-18 / 2015-12-31

•   Training dataset: first 1162 USDlogreturns observations

•   Test dataset: last 800 USDlogreturns observations

•   Number of steps ahead: 1 day

•   Number of rolling forecasts: 800

•   Model refitting window: every 100 days

EDIT:

I tried the following basic code based on the following post. This is supposed to compute 800 rolling forecasts without refitting every 100 days. If it works with the fix I need, then I'll try the related code with model refitting.

[Obtaining results as a matrix in a self created r function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38113485/obtaining-results-as-a-matrix-in-a-self-created-r-function)

```
data<-USDlogreturns
window<-window(USDlogreturns, from=1, to=1162)
step<-1
SlideFunction<- function(data, window, step) {
  total<- length(data)
  spots<- seq(from=1, to=(total-window), by=step)
  fcasts<- matrix(NA, nrow=length(spots), ncol=121)
  for(i in 1:length(spots)) {
    for(j in 1:121){
      p<- result[j,1]
      q<- result[j,3]
      fit <- Arima(data[spots[i]:(spots[i]+window)], order=c(p,0,q), method="ML", include.mean=TRUE)
      fcasts[i, j] <- forecast(fit, h=step)$mean 
      }
    }
  return(fcasts)
}

SlideFunction(data,window,step)
```

The problem with my code is that I get the following error message:

"in seq.default(from = 1, to = (total - window), by = step) : 'to' must be of length 1"

What's wrong with my code? Thank you.

PS: I am a rookie of R coding for loops. So sorry for asking maybe simple questions.

Comment: I just had a quick look at your code. I think you should initialize `fit` outside the for loop, i.e. `fit <- list()`. Then, inside the loop, you should write `fit[i][[j]] <- ` instead of `fit <- `, otherwise you overwrite at each iteration. At the end of the iterations, check what `fit` contains by simply running `str(fit)`: you may find your answer or at least some more insights.

Comment: I get this error message if I enter SlideFunction(window, 800, 1):"Error in if (!is.numeric(order) || length(order) != 3L || any(order <  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

Comment: Still I cannot find where I'm wrong. I keep on getting the error message that I posted in my code. Does anyone can provide me with some help? I have been stuck for days on this.